# Como publicar múltiplas aplicações Laravel em Servidor Compartilhado?

Tags: php, laravel, servidor, framework, hospedagem

Tenho duas aplicação independentes feitas em Laravel gostaria de hospedá-las no mesmo servidor, em diretórios separados.

Procurei intensivamente na documentação e em fóruns, e consegui fazer somente uma aplicação funcionar corretamente, porém, todos os arquivos de configuração ficaram vulneráveis a acesso via URL e não quero de forma alguma fazer a configuração arquivo por arquivo do que pode ou não pode ser acessado no arquivo de configuração .htaccess.

Qual é a melhor forma de publicar múltiplas aplicação em laravel no mesmo servidor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando um servidor Apache você pode criar Virtual Hosts, no qual você pode redirecionar uma URL do servidor para ser servida de outro diretório como mencionado [nesta documentação do apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Neste arquivo de exemplo duas aplicações rodam no mesmo servidor com urls diferentes e diretórios diferentes, a URL não precisa ser necessariamente dominios diferentes, podem ser apenas pastas, eu já fiz usando apenas pastas diferentes.

O DocumentRoot para você será a pasta onde está o laravel, o servername é a sua url. Para isso vale a pena dar uma olhada nos Alias e nas diretivas Directory que controlam o acesso a URL.

Ainda em relação aos arquivos de Configuração por não estarem na pasta public eles já deveriam estar seguros, caso acredite precisar de mais seguraná você pode passar as configurações para o [Apache como variaveis de ambiente](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/env.html) e acessando elas pelo PHP com o [$_ENV](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.environment.php).

Caso esteja usando o NGINX ele também permite este tipo de operação.

Comment: Consegui resolver este problema facilmente utilizando o serviço Jelastic da Locaweb. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver a usar cPanel com softaculous, experimente instalar o Laravel através do installer do softaculous, não manualmente.

Ai vai ter forma de instalar em directórios separados e o softaculous vai configurar tudo certinho.